# Erro de sintaxe - a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition

Tags: c, funções

Estou com dificuldade para entender porque minha declaração de função dá o erro:

```
a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition int fib(n) = fib(n - 1) + fib (n - 2);
```

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fib(int n){ 
    int fib(n) = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    if(n == 0){ 
        return fib(0) = 1;
    }
    else{ 
        return fib(n) = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }
}
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", fib(n));
}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Eu fiz um código para sequência de Fibonacci, mas está chegando mensagem de erro : "a parenter list without types is only allowed in a function definition int fib(n) = fib(n - 1) + fib (n - 2);"

Comment: `int fib(n) = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)` - esta sintaxe não existe, pois `fib(n)` está chamando a função, e vc está tentando atribuir um valor nesta chamada, como se fosse uma variável. O mesmo vale para os `return`'s. Deveria ser apenas `int fib(int n) { if (n <= 1) { return 1; } else { return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2); } }`

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
int fib(int n){
    // Chamar a função fib antes do if resultaria em recursão infinita
    // cada vez que a função fib(n) fosse chamada novamente, cairia nessa linha antes
    // de qualquer coisa, e nunca iria para frente, apenas mais fundo.

    // Em fibonacci, não é apenas 0 que retorna 1, quando n = 1, fib também será 1.
    // Caso mantivesse a condição anterior (n==0), seu programa faria a 
    // chamada fib(1), que cairia no else lá embaixo, que faz a chamada fib(n-2) 
    // resultando em fib(-1) o que por sua vez faria infinitas chamadas negativas.
    if( n<=1 ){
        // não é preciso chamar a função aqui, muito menos atribuir um valor. 
        // Apenas retorne o resultado.
        return  1;
        // Sempre que fizer uma função recursiva, é importante estabelecer uma condição
        // que não vai chamar a função novamente, para impedir um loop infinito
    }
    else{
        // novamente, não é preciso chamar fib(n) aqui. 
        // Isso é feito lá embaixo dentro de printf().
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }
}
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", fib(n));
    // main() não é uma função tipo void,
    // então precisa retornar alguma coisa, mesmo que seja 0
    return 0;
}
```

Quando programando em C, você não atribui um tipo à uma função quando faz uma chamada dela. No seu programa, a linha 2 declara a função e atribui um tipo (`int fib( int n )`). Depois que sua função está declarada, você simplesmente chama ela, `x = fib(y);`, sem precisar colocar um `int ali`.

Outra coisa: você confundiu o significado da linha `fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);`. Essa linha é um erro de sintaxe. Em programação, o caractere `=` serve para atribuir um valor à uma variável, não para escrever uma equação. Você cria uma variável `int x;` e então atribui um valor à ela `x = 1 + 2;`.

A função `fib()` **não** é uma variável. A função é uma série de cálculos que retorna um valor. Aí você usa o caractere `=` para armazenar esse valor em um espaço da memória que você reservou para a variável (você faz isso com a declaração `int x;`, onde `x` agora é o espaço de memória reservado), ou imprime o valor na tela.

O computador interpreta o programa assim: Quando ele vê um `=` ele sabe que vai vir um valor numérico que precisa ser armazenado. Então ele executa o cálculo do lado direito do `=`, e armazena na variável do lado esquerdo.

Comment: Poxa amg, muito obrigado. Sua explicação foi super completa e detalhada. Ajudou bastante. Agora está rodando. Muito obg:)